# Can't access my router

Tags: ip, router

192.169.1.1 or 192.168.1.254 is not working. Neither from windows. I have a custom IP. I have tried with auto IP and when I type this IP in the address bar I connect to someone else's router because they have not disabled the dhpc (I live in a campus at university). How to ensure I  only access my router?The ethernet is starting from university goes to a spliter after to my  router(for wifi) then on my pc via ethernet.When I connect the  erthernet to PC-modem and disconnect the connection modem-switcher ubuntu does not  connect to a wired connection. DHPC on my modem is off. I have only ethernet adaptor. Router ZTE ZXHN H108L and the ip is 192.168.1.254.I have only ethernet adaptor. ZTE ZXHN H108L and the ip is 192.168.1.254.  When i connect the ethernet that goes to switcher and i put static ip ubuntu connects to internet. When I put out the ethernet that goes to switcher and I put auto IP  ubuntu doesnt recognize a wired connection

```
dimitris@dimitris-G31M-ES2L:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         150.140.216.126 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
150.140.216.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0



dimitris@dimitris-G31M-ES2L:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:52:c2:20:05  
          inet addr:150.140.216.42  Bcast:150.140.216.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:52ff:fec2:2005/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2381 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1403 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:694713 (694.7 KB)  TX bytes:231115 (231.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1410 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1410 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:110892 (110.8 KB)  TX bytes:110892 (110.8 KB)
```

When i connect the modem only with my PC

```
dimitris@dimitris-G31M-ES2L:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:52:c2:20:05  
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e0:52ff:fec2:2005/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22753 errors:0 dropped:42 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10501 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:6
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4641316 (4.6 MB)  TX bytes:1870972 (1.8 MB)
```

Comment: Is your pc the only one on the network ?

Comment: From the swicher are 100 pc conected. From my modem it is just mine

Comment: My idea was to use `arp` command. If a pc is the only one that communicates with router, `arp` shows the appropriate ip address. But with multiple pcs, there's gonna be output for those as well ( the  broadcast often sends out "whohas ip" requests to all hosts )

Comment: When i connect the router ONLY with my PC with auto IP ubuntu is trying to connect with it but it can't. It is like offline

Comment: Check your network, if there is your router, you should see him: `nmap 150.140.216.0/24`

Comment: I think, your router is `150.140.216.126`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to run 'route -n' where you can see your gateways. Here you will have the IP of the gateway (or gateways) you are using now. Type this IP to access to the router.

It is difficult to guess from you question the problem, we really do not know how you are connected to your router (wireless? a second ethernet card?) But if you can connect to a different router and you are using only one ethernet card, probably you are in the wrong network.

Comment: The ethernet is starting from university goes to a spliter after to my  router(for wifi) then on my pc via ethernet

Comment: You need to connect directly to you router through its ethernet port (or switch) for configuring. In some models you can also use the wireless for configuration if already available.

Comment: Yes I am conected to router directly but i cant access it. Look the out put of route -n

Comment: With your last edit, now I see that you only have available your university network. As you are connected to a switch, that also is connected to the university network, your IP is given by the other router (probably the router of the university).  First of all, I recommend you to ONLY connect your PC to the router, configure it and later connect to the network. Probably, if your networks need some credentials to connect (I assume it) your router will not be allowed to connect to the network directly, only your computer where you put the credentials.

Comment: I have tried it. When I connect the  erthernet to PC-modem and disconnect the connection modem-switcher ubuntu does not  connect to a wired connection.DHPC of my modem is off

Comment: Sounds strange. Are you sure your device is working and you are connecting to the right port (LAN and not WAN)? Do you know the correct IP of the device?  Could you post the model of the "PC-modem"?

Comment: I have only ethernet adaptor. ZTE ZXHN H108L and the ip is 192.168.1.254.  When i connect the ethernt that goes to switcher and i put static ip ubuntu connects to internet. When I put out the ethernet that goes to switcher and I put auto IP  ubuntu doesnt recognize a wired connection

Comment: I see, it is an ADSL router. It has no WAN interface and therefore it would be impossible to connect to your university network using it. The router expects PC clients in the switch, and therefore, does not try to access to internet through it. It would try to connect using the phone connection as an external network. Nevertheless, I assume your university network uses some kind of security/credentials that you cannot configure in your router on this way (and of course, this is not related to ubuntu configuration)

Comment: Returning to the original question, you need to connect first to the router, with no other connection (your pc directly connected to the router without connect to the external switch) and you need to set the IP of your computer with 'ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.1' or the ip in range depending on the router configuration.  Only then you can connect to the router.

Comment: Ubuntu doesnt recognize my modem that is the problem. I dont care for the whole network. I just want to change security key and i cant

Comment: Ok, try this: ''ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.2' in a console (with sudo or root). Then try to use 'ping  192.168.1.1' that is probably the default IP of your router. If you have a response, open the browser and connect to the web page of the router.

Comment: I did it but ubuntu is not connected with the wired conection. Windows were connected to modem ( i couldn't acceess the modem) but the default gateway was blank.

Comment: Your Windows connection is correct. Make sense that the gateway is blank. Your router has no internet/WAN connection and therefore is not acting as gateway to another different network.  On ubuntu, I really do not understand what means 'is not connected with the wired conection'. At least, with ifconfig command I gave you, you must have IP. If the device eth0 is not shown when doing ifconfig, try 'ifconfig eth0 up' to enable it.

Comment: I mean when i connect the modem only with  pc ubuntu is offline it says no connection. Please look the ip config when router is conected only with my PC

Comment: Probably, because it is not connected to Internet, what is true due to your router has no internet connection. Try the commands I have told you before, and if the 'ping' is working then you can see your route and therefore you are able to change the key of your wireless.

Comment: Ok So you say to connect the router to internet, after to do  ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.2 on terminal and after to type 192.168.1.1 on adress bar to access it?

Comment: No, you do not need internet connection to access to the router configuration page. But your ubuntu can point to that you do not have internet connection with an alert message (two different things). Ignore the message 'no connection' and set the ip of your machine using the previous command. Then you can type the IP on the address bar.

Comment: I am assuming that the router has the IP 192.168.1.1 (the default one).

Comment: No this 192.168.1.1 connects me to oneother router. I typed 192.168.1.254 and worked.  I saw it from arp. If you want edit your answer i will pick it as solution!

Comment: Glad to see that finally is working.